# Cambiar el tamaño de una Imagen con JavaScript y onchage

Tags: javascript

Tengo una funcion que es para cambiar el tamaño de una imagen que despues ocupare para enviar por post.
Carge la funcion para que funcione con el evento on change del input type="file"
y no funciona, pero si le agrego un boton con esa funcion y lo ejecuto despues de cargar la imagen en el input si funciona.
No entiendo el porque y como debo hacerlo para que funcione con el on change.
aqui el codigo.
debe ser algo realacionado a el orden en el que se ejecuta el codigo o el tiempo.
tambien probe con setTimeOut

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input id="foto" type="file" accept="image/*" > 
    <input type="button" value="Resize Image"  onclick="ResizeImage()"/> 
    <input type="text" id="info">
    <img src="" id="output">
   
</div>
</body>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById('foto').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            ResizeImage();
        }); 
    });

function ResizeImage() {
    var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('foto').files;
    var file = filesToUpload[0];
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var MAX_WIDTH = 600;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;

            if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById('output').src = dataurl;
            document.getElementById('info').value=dataurl;           
        }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);   
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: El evento change no es compatible con un elemento tipo file, tal como se ve en este artículo: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event ¿cuando pretendes exáctamente que se produzca el resize? ¿Al hacer click en la imagen?

Comment: @chikebox la idea es que después de seleccionar un archivo de imagen con el input inmediatamente después de eso la imagen cambie su tamaño sin necesidad que el usuario tenga que hacer nada más, porque después de eso debe presiona un botón de enviar donde se enviara por ajax (FormData) los datos a un servidor incluida la imagen. esto lo necesito hacer porque cuando la página la abren desde un teléfono, y toman una foto con los teléfonos modernos las imágenes son muy grandes y pesadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te puede ayudar este hilo:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759386/resize-image-in-the-client-side-before-upload , es exáctamente lo que quieres hacer :D, la principal diferencia que veo con tu codigo es sobre el tema del capturador de eventos, si estas utilizando JQuery, cosa que me figuro porque estás usando `$`, no necesitas añadir a los elementos del html `eventListener` simplemente con las funciones `.onChange`, `.onClick`, `.onLoQueTuQuieras` ya haces esa funcionalidad.

Sólo tienes que sustituir su código dentro de la linea:

```
fileInput.onchange = function change() {
    //Tu codigo
}
```

Comment: Funciono de mil maravillas, muchas gracias habia buscado algun hilo que me ayudara pero este fue el exacto que necesitaba