# asignarle el nombre de un input file a un input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

hola quiero asignarle al input con id asignarNombreArchivo  el nombre del archivo del input file  csv.

asi lo tengo pero funciona hasta la segunda vez

```js
$( "#seleccionarArchivo" ).click(function() {
    $( "#csv" ).click();
    if( document.getElementById("csv").files.length == 0 ){ 
        console.log("no files selected"); 
    }else{
        nombreArc = $( "#csv" ).val();
        $('#asignarNombreArchivo').val(nombreArc);
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 noPadding">
                    <label for="cv">
                        Adjunta tu CV
                    </label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 noPadding inputLeft">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Elige tu archivo" id="asignarNombreArchivo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 noPadding inputRight">
                            <input hidden type="file" name="csv" id="csv" accept="application/pdf, .doc, .docx, .odf" required>
                            <p href="#" class="btn btnTerciary btnFull" id="seleccionarArchivo">Buscar</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu duda?

Comment: perdon no me fije que no habia puesto el problema

Comment: Cambia el evento _click_ por _change_, porque al hacer clic no se ha seleccionado todavía un archivo.

Comment: @Triby _change_ escuchara los cambios. Si el primera cambio que se realices es el de cancelar no lo detectara.

Comment: @Link_HG, exacto y no habrá cambio.

Comment: @Triby supuse que el OP quería interactuar con el resultado final del evento; de no ser así _change_ como comentas funcionara muy bien.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cambiar el tamaño de una Imagen con JavaScript y onchage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/311251/cambiar-el-tama%c3%b1o-de-una-imagen-con-javascript-y-onchage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que la llamada a `click()` del elemento `#csv` no espera a que el usuario termine de seleccionar y cierre el cuadro de diálogo para devolver el control al programa, sino que la siguiente línea se ejecuta inmediatamente.

Para cuando el usuario presiona el botón *Aceptar* del diálogo, ya no se está ejecutando nada de tu código.

Por eso mismo tienes la *ilusión* que no funciona la primera pero si la segunda vez, aunque la segunda vez te va a mostrar el archivo seleccionado la primera, no el que se selecciona la segunda, por lo ya dicho.

Puedes valerte del evento `change` del `input` para *reaccionar* a los cambios que se producen en este control.

Cambiando de lugar tu código, y poniendo todo en una función de inicialización, luce así:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#seleccionarArchivo").click(function() {
        $("#csv").click();
    });
    
    $("input:file").change(function (){
        var fileName = $(this).val();
        console.log(fileName);
        if( document.getElementById("csv").files.length == 0 ) { 
            console.log("no files selected"); 
        } else {
            nombreArc = $( "#csv" ).val();
            $('#asignarNombreArchivo').val(nombreArc);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 noPadding">
                    <label for="cv">
                        Adjunta tu CV
                    </label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 noPadding inputLeft">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Elige tu archivo" id="asignarNombreArchivo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 noPadding inputRight">
                            <input hidden type="file" name="csv" id="csv" accept="application/pdf, .doc, .docx, .odf" required>
                            <p href="#" class="btn btnTerciary btnFull" id="seleccionarArchivo">Buscar</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias todo quedo bien